# Result document for each sub node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have XML source like:

```
<book>
<body>
    <div data-type="book" id="book">
        <p>content</p>
                    <p>para 1</p>
                    <p>para 2</p>
                    <p>para 3</p>
        <div id="chapter1" data-type="chapter">
                    <p>para 1</p>
                    <p>para 2</p>
                    <p>para 3</p>
            <div id="lesson1" data-type="lesson">
                <div data-type="body">
                    <p>para 1</p>
                    <p>para 2</p>
                    <p>para 3</p>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</book>
```

I am creating an output folder and files based on the id value like:

```
book1.xml
book1/ 
 chapter1.xml
 chapter1/
    lesson1.xml
    lesson2.xml
```

my XSLT is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="div" mode="path">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template
    match="div[@data-type='book' or @data-type='chapter' or @data-type='lesson']">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="content">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::div" mode="path"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:result-document href="output/{$content}/{@id}.xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Issue:

I am getting the correct folder and file structure using the above XSLT. But when creating book1.xml and chapter.xml and lesson.xml it's not copying the entire content. book1.xml doesn't have the chapter content in it. What I need is book1.xml should has entire content of book. chapter.xml should has entire content of chapter including lessons.

Comment: Can you show an example of the actual content of the "book1.xml", "chapter1.xml" and "lesson.xml" files you are trying to create here? Thanks!

Comment: Book1.xml should be with entire the <book>...</book> content, chapter1.xml should be with entire <div data-type="chapter">...</div> content and lesson1.xml should have only lesson content but should be in their respective folders

Answer (score 1):

If you want the content of all chapters to appear in the book output as well as in the appropriate chapter output, just add another `<xsl:apply-templates/>` call immediate before (or after) the `xsl:result-document` instruction.

Comment: I am already using    <xsl:result-document href="output/{$content}/{@id}.xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:result-document>  but it gives the content other than div within the book

Comment: Yes I know you have an apply-templates instruction within the result-document instruction, add another one outside it.